# Deserialize DateTime from MongoDB to PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, datetime, serialization

I inserted a `DateTime` in MongoDB,

how to reconstruct this object?

```
$mongo->insert(array('time' => new DateTime()));
```

Output when using `find` is:

```
[time] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2014-10-26 23:11:29.000000
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
    )
```

I know I can use

```
DateTime::createFromFormat(...);
```

But is there a more convenient way?

Comment: You can use native serialization `$mongo->insert(array('time' => serialize(new DateTime())));` `var_dump(unserialize($array['time']));` Not sure this is more convenient though

Comment: You're using the wrong object for datetime in mongodb. see the duplicate closed against.